# pandoc stopped working: "! LaTeX Error: File `ifxetex.sty' not found."

Tags: pandoc, pdflatex

I woke up and pandoc stopped working.

I have this file test.md:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
---

# Header

Hello world
```

and when I run `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf` I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ifxetex.sty' not found.
```

But it *is* installed. Nothing about my TeX distribution (MacTex) changed. And so far as I can tell nothing about pandoc changed.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** `ifxetex` is part of `iftex` (https://ctan.org/pkg/ifxetex?lang=en) and I confirmed I already have `iftex` by trying to install it and getting the message:

```
tlmgr install: package already present: iftex
```

Comment: sounds like a problem with your latex installation... see also https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf for debugging tips